# Check if site uses Basic Auth via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, basic-authentication

Is there a way to check via AJAX, if a website uses Basic Authorization, without letting the browser display the login dialog box?

My current call is:

```
$.ajax
    type: 'HEAD'
    url: url
    success: (data) ->
         console.log 'jep'
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
         console.log 'nope'
```

This will always display the login dialog box if the site uses authorization. However, I just want to know if the site is protected with a basic authorization or not. I couldn't find a way to do so. I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616277/ajax-authentication-without-letting-browser-pop-up-login-dialog) solution, but I can't edit the server response.

Comment: What have you tried? The 401 response might trigger your `error` handler. Maybe you could try logging more information than *"nope"*

Comment: `Success` and `error` are triggered after the dialog shows up.

Comment: Sending the wrong username and password isn't working and the 401 statusCode trigger gets also fired after the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Check the headers. If you see something like this:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="protected-area"
```

...then you know it uses basic authentication. So check for the presence of the above header.